# How Do Ground-Mounted Verticals Compare to Elevated Verticals?

Tags: vertical-antenna, radial, counterpoise, buried

Their performance differences may be less than sometimes expected.

Comment: I posted the information in this thread as an edit to the thread at the URL provided above by rclocher3.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a graphic comparing some of the operational parameters of ground-mounted and elevated vertical radiators for the 40-meter band.

Their performance when installed at sites with relatively poor Earth conductivity is fairly similar.

[image]

Comment: Interesting!  I had always thought that the performance of a vertical with elevated radials was better than that of a vertical with radials buried in earth of poor conductivity.

Comment: @rclocher3 Not better, but from the publications of N6LF (Dr. Rudy Severns) and others, I thought they could be the same. Please scroll past the table and graphs down to the "Relevant links" section [**here**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180815154501/http://w0btu.com/Optimum_number_of_ground_radials_vs_radial_length.html) and you can read them. Rich, this is new to me, and if this wasn't your answer I may have downvoted it instead of upvoting it. :-)

Comment: rclocher3 commented: _I had always thought that the performance of a vertical with elevated radials was better than that of a vertical with radials buried in earth of poor conductivity._  –- Even for the 1 mS/m conductivity curves in my graphic, the red trace would be nearly identical to the green trace IF the vertical with buried radials was using 120 of them instead of 32.